# Angular SSR change styles on it's own with ng2-adsense

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, server-side-rendering, adsense

when placing ads with ng2-adsense in the  `/about` component for example and change the view with router-outlet and  routing to `/about` the the **footer leaves the bottom** , i use flexbox css to set the footer, i looked into console and noticed extra styles that dynamically gets added [new styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqJrM.png)

my styles

[style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmgFO.png)

have no clue, and don't get it

Comment: Please add code as text, not as images